# Asking the user to create a new object?

Tags: java, list, class, object

I am working on a Car Dealership program for a Java course, basically I have to create a objects of a car and add that object into a linked list then retrieve information from that car object. My question is how would i ask a user to create a new car object with the following attributes related to the car?

so something like this: Car car10 = new Car(...); but instead of me direct typing it in the main I want a user to input the information.

I hope this makes sense, more detailed info: http://printupon.ca/humber/course/CENG212/Labs/proj05_CarDealer.htm

I put the code I have so far written on github for simplicity sake and also you can ignore all the commented out code, that is for my personal testing purposes. Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!

code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b3afe93034dc63b45fd1

Comment: You are looking for a `Car Factory` :P. Which takes arguments sent by user and returns a brand new Car (object). A simple constructor with parameters would work as well.

Comment: Do you mean creating a car using an input from the user? i.e. a web based screen or console input? well In both ways you can ask for the required input from the user and you can create a Car directly using a constructor or using Factory pattern as Vinod suggested.

Comment: Is Car Factory a java api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read user inputs this way:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter Brand");
        String brand = br.readLine();
...
```

or using **[scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)**

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int i = in.nextInt();
String input = in.next();
```

than instead of your

```
Car car = new Car("Honda", "Civic", "Grey", 1998, 183958, 3200);
```

fill them with values readed from `BufferedReader` or `Scanner`

```
Car car = new Car(brand, ...)
//regarding to your comment
carList.add(car);
```

Comment: Okay I understand that but what about the naming of object Cars, like car1, car2, car3 etc...? I am confused as how I would increment that variable

Comment: @S.Q you have it in your question. "..car and add that object into a linked list.." create loop in main, ask user for information create car and put it into linked list. Repeat as many times as you want. You don't need to have more variables of car.